# Spring Boot continuous testing

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, quarkus

> Quarkus supports continuous testing, where tests run immediately after
> code changes have been saved. This allows you to get instant feedback
> on your code changes. Quarkus detects which tests cover which code,
> and uses this information to only run the relevant tests when code is
> changed.

Does the Spring Boot 3(RC1) also provide continuous testing?
**HINT:** I am using Intellj as IDE.

Comment: No this is not contained in Spring Boot 3